# Summing columns with nested sums/loops in gnuplot

Tags: loops, plot, gnuplot, nested-loops

I want to sum values from the following columns which indexes are (16, 18, 20, 24, 26, 28, 32, 34, 36) with gnuplot's commands without typing the indexes explicitly.

I know there's a command to sum values of different columns which indexes can be expressed with a function of a variable:

```
plot 'data' using 1 : (sum [col=8:10] column(col*2))
```

The problem is that the indexes in my case can only be described with two variables, thus need nested loops/sums. The pseudo-code for the index would be

```
for i=0:2 {for j=0:2 { index = ( j + 8 + i*4 ) * 2 } }
```

Is there a way to do nested summations or for-loops in gnuplot?

Answer (score 0):

All iterations in gnuplot work recursively.  No special syntax is needed to nest one inside another. E.g.

```
filename(n,m) = sprintf("NAME_%d_%d.dat",n,m)
plot for [i=1:5] for [j=i:5] filename(i,j)
```